# run problem in packettracer6.2 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cisco

I installed packettracer6.2 in ubuntu 16.04. successfully installed but when i type packettracer in terminal then nothing happens except for "starting packettracer 6.2".How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

At first check your system integrity and install all upgrades:

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Let's assume that you have extracted your CPT distribution to `~/Downloads/PacketTracer62`. So `cd ~/Downloads/PacketTracer62`

Then run `sudo ./install`.

By default it will install to `/opt/cpt`, it runs `apt-get` by installer and then create symlink in `/usr/local/bin`.

During installation I got error messages about `lib32bz2-1.0` package, but after installation I can launch `packettracer` on my 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

It seems that `apt-get` part failed on your machine. You can try to reinstall CPT with `sudo ./install` again. Or install all needed packages by hand:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32tinfo5 gcc-6-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 gcc-5-base:i386 libstdc++6:i386 \
libc6-dev:i386 libssl-dev:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386 \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libbsd0:i386 \
libcap2:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 \
libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 \
libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 \
libgnutls30:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhogweed4:i386 \
libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 \
libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libllvm5.0:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient20:i386 libnettle6:i386 \
libogg0:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 \
libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 \
libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsensors4:i386 libsm6:i386 \
libsqlite3-0:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libuuid1:i386 \
libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 \
libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 \
libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common qt-at-spi:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

And for sure install missed `lib32bz2-1.0` package from Trusty

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bzip2/lib32bz2-1.0_1.0.6-5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./lib32bz2-1.0_1.0.6-5_amd64.deb
```

and rerun CPT installation (confirming overwrites):

```
sudo ./install
```